# How to define which diagonals belong to concave polygon

Tags: algorithm, geometry, triangulation, polygons

I have problem with triangulation algorithm:
[image]

In concave polygons some diagonals are not in polygon. I have double connected list of edges,vertex and know which vertex have concave angle.

There is 2 cases:

A) diagonal intersection with edge or another diagonal.
B) diagonal dont intersection any, but is out of polygon.

How i can define diagonals in A and B cases?

Comment: But you don't need this algortihm to triangulate convex polygon

Comment: What is your question? In a convex polygon, all diagonals lie inside.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - i have concave polygon :)

Comment: Great, it does make sense this way.  Now what is the question?

Comment: Do you realize that algo is intended for Y-monotone polygons?

Comment: @MBo yes, i have already algorith makeMonotone in my program (and it works :D), now i try write triangulation alg.

Comment: @shinobi how i can define when diagonal is not in interior of polygon? i need separate diagonals belong to polygon from not belong.

Comment: @dzida I've been scratching my head over this, and I think you probably only need to consider potential intersections with edges connecting "the other" vertices already popped under the one in consideration -- otherwise, the algorithm would seem to be pointless.  You had better look twice for an explanation in the text though -- it would be rather odd if it simply glossed over such a major point.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this sample, where **vertices are sorted in clockwise order**:

[image]

Look at the red diagonals, outside the polygon. Vertex '4' is at right of line '3-5'. Vertices '3, 4' are at right of line '2-5'.

We can infer a law: If a line `i-j` has some vertex `k` with `i < k < j` that is at right of the line, then that line is external to the polygon.

Notice that if you reverse the order of the vertices, then the you must also use "at left" instead of "at right".

Comment: You're talking about *vectors*, not *lines*, you need do define "left" and "right", and you need to fix the division of vertices (i < k < j won't cut it).  Sadly, though, even after fixing all of the above, it still won't work -- consider the 1-4 diagonal as a counter-example.

Comment: i solved that. if we are point "2" at edge 1-2. Then we need to find angle between 1-2 and 2-3 and angle between 2-3 and 2-5. 

 if angle between new diagonal and edge is higher than first angle, then this diagonal not belong to polygon.

correct me if this is wrong idea